# to_categorical returns 2 column matrix

Tags: python, numpy, keras, python-3.5

I used the to_categorical function provided in keras to convert a numpy ndarray of type float to its binary counterpart. Dimensions of Y were 2144x1 but the dimensions of the array returned by the function were 2144x2.
How do I get a 2144x1 array from to_categorical?
Y comprises of only 0s and 1s (FLOAT TYPE)
Function Call:

```
y_binary = to_categorical(Y)
```

Comment: If you already have 0s and 1s why don´t you just convert the type from float to boolean with `Y.astype(bool)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=None)`

Converts a class vector (integers) to binary class matrix.

But it doesn't looks like it supports float (its doing floor for all numbers)

```
to_categorical([0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 1])
[[ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.]]


to_categorical([0, 1, 2, 3, 1])
[[ 1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.]]
```

One solution is, scale it up to positive integers and convert to categorical.